# Change active bootstrap nav-Item with angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

In my angular 6 project I am using bootstrap 4, in particular I am using `nav-pills` and I want to change the active `nav-item` from the component.

so How can I set the active nav from component?.

`$('#someTab').tab('show')` from [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#via-javascript) seems not work form me.

this is the **NAV-PILLS**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-warning" role="tablist">
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#link1" role="tablist">
         Profile
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#link2" role="tablist">
             Settings
       </a>
    </li>
 </ul>


<div class="tab-content tab-space">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="link1">
   Collaboratively administrate .......
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="link2">
    Efficiently unleash......
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried in Angular? What's not working?

Comment: @ZimSystem question edited